# upload file using ssh

Tags: node.js, ssh, scp

I'm able to upload/download a file from my local windows pc on my server through ssh connection by using scp command, for example the following command works fine:
scp -r /local/myFolderWithFiles mySshServer@192.168.x.y:~/Documents/subFolder

So I've tried to perform the same action using nodejs with scp package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-scp), but when I use the uploadFile function, no file is uploaded, nor do I get any errors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by myselfe.
Simply, I needed to specify the full path instead of ~Documents, namely:
/Users/MyUser/Documents.